# The massive Thirring model

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, conservation-laws

I am trying to find conservation laws in the following coupled equations:

\begin{equation}
-af(x) + i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + g(x) + |g(x)|^2 f(x) = 0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
-ag(x) - i\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} + f(x) + |f(x)|^2 g(x) = 0
\end{equation}

Where $a$ is a constant and $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are complex valued functions. To simplify the problem I need to find a conservation law. I have tried multiplying the top equation be $f^*$ and the bottom one by $g^*$, where $^*$ denotes a conjugate, and subtracting the two. I got the following:

\begin{equation}
a(|g|^2-|f|^2) + i(f^*f_x-g^*g_x)+f^*g-g^*f = 0
\end{equation}

Any insights into how I could find any conservation laws would be much obliged, also the following ansatz may be useful:
\begin{equation}
f(x) = pe^{i\theta(x)}\\
g(x) = qe^{i\phi(x)}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The equation system is a coupled set of [non-linear Schrödinger equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation). Here is a trick: The Lagrangian
reads$^1$ 
$$\tag{1} L~=~ i\dot{f}f^{\ast}- i\dot{g}g^{\ast}-a|f|^2-a|g|^2+gf^{\ast}+fg^{\ast} +|f|^2|g|^2 ,$$
where we have assumed that the constant $a\in\mathbb{R}$ is real. Show that the Lagrangian (1) possesses a global $U(1)$ phase symmetry 
$ f~\to~ fe^{i\phi}, ~ g~\to~ ge^{i\phi},$ with corresponding conserved [Noether charge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) 
$ Q~=~i|f|^2-i|g|^2.$

--

$^1$ The signs in front of various terms in the Lagrangian (1) are non-conventional, but we don't care, since we are only interested in the equations of motion.

Comment: Yep there have been some development, and I am able to show that $|f| = |g|$ (since we require a vanishing solution at infinity).

Comment: ...corresponding to zero charge $Q=0$.